# SQL Query; Return all records of main table and add field from joined table on condition; leave value empty when no match in joined table found

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

Scenario is like this (I am using SQLite):

**Main table books:**

```
CREATE TABLE "books" (
    "bookId"    integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "bookName"  nvarchar NOT NULL COLLATE NOCASE
);
```

**Foreign key table booksLang:**

```
    CREATE TABLE "booksLang" (
    "bookLangId"    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "BookId"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "LanguageID"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "BookName"  TEXT
);
```

**Data in books:**

```
bookId     BookName
1          Genesis
2          Exodus
3          Leviticus
4          Numbers
5          Deuteronomy
```

**Data in booksLang:**

```
bookLangId      BookId     LanguageID     BookName_Localization
1               1          12             Genèse
2               2          12             Exode
3               1          10             Schöpfung
4               4          10             Zahlen
```

**Question:**
How does the query has to look like when the given languageID is 12 and the following result has to come out (the tables books and booksLang are "somehow" joined - but tell me how):

```
bookId     BookName     BookName_Localization
1          Genesis      Genèse
2          Exodus       Exode
3          Leviticus    ----- (none because there is no localization)
4          Numbers      ----- (none because there is no localization)
5          Deuteronomy  ----- (none because there is no localization)
```

If the languageID is 10 the result has to look like this:

```
bookId     BookName     BookName_Localization
1          Genesis      Schöpfung
2          Exodus       ----- (none because there is no localization)
3          Leviticus    ----- (none because there is no localization)
4          Numbers      Zahlen
5          Deuteronomy  ----- (none because there is no localization)
```

As I am no SQL expert, I do not get it how always to retrieve all records from books table and retrieve BookName_Localization from the joined but retrieve "null" or something similar in it.

Also there could be localizations in many different languages but the resultset must always only contain exactly 1 record for each main record (not less or more) - enriched with the BookName_Localization field from the joined booksLang table for a given LanguageID. The value of this additional field either contains the localized text for the given language if it exists - or, if it does not exist - must be empty.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

*Edited because of bad formatting

Comment: Why the downvote? This was a legitimate question, well documented from my side - and I really didn't know the answer at that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are describing a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select b.*, bl.bookname
from books b left join
     bookslang bl
     on bl.BookId = b.BookId and bl.languageId = 12
```

Comment: omg - thanks, yes - that's absolutely it - this time I really have missed it!